# JavaFX items stay null

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a GUI for a application and I have run into a problem when trying to change items after the `fxmlloader` loaded a file in.

At the start I thought it was that I wanted to edit the items before they were initialised (the rendering of the file was still going and i tried to edit the items before that was done). But then I tried to make a timer that every second (for testing purposes such a long time) checked the state of the object and if the object wasn't null it would do something.

However I noticed that the items never stop being null and thus I can't edit them. Anyone has a idea how to change this? I get this problem with Text and GridPane objects so far but not with buttons :/

The controller (the part that matters):

```
protected void sceneSetter(String filename) {
    //loads the FXMLFile of the right sceneand makes the scene 1280x720 (720p)
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(filename));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("RIP scene setting");
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
    //sets the right scene and displays it
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    if(filename.equals("/InterfaceUserChange.fxml")){
        final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("tried it");
                if(firstLoginContainer != null){
                    TextField field = new TextField() {
                        @Override public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
                            // If the replaced text would end up being invalid, then simply
                            // ignore this call!
                            if (!text.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                                super.replaceText(start, end, text);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override public void replaceSelection(String text) {
                            if (!text.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                                super.replaceSelection(text);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    firstLoginContainer.add(field , 1 , 1);
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });

        if(firstLoginContainer == null) {
            timer.start();
        }
        System.out.println("textfield added?");
    }
```

The `fxml` file (its in a borderpane):

```
<left>
    <VBox fx:id="firstLoginPaneContainer">
        <HBox styleClass="profilePane">
            <VBox styleClass="pictureDummy">
                <ImageView>
                    <Image url="@testpica200px.jpg"/>
                </ImageView>
            </VBox>
            <GridPane styleClass="firstLoginContainer"
                      alignment="TOP_LEFT" hgap="10" vgap="10">

                <padding>
                    <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25"/>
                </padding>

                <Text text="Name: "
                      GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
                <TextField fx:id="changeName"
                           GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>

                <Text text="Age: "
                      GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>


                <Text text="Study: "
                      GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>

                <Text text="Courses: "
                      GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>

                <Text text="Preferences: " fx:id="selfPreferences"
                      GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>

                <Text text="E-mail: " fx:id="changeEmail"
                      GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
                <Text text="Phone number: " fx:id="selfPhonenumber"
                      GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
            </GridPane>
        </HBox>
    </VBox>
</left>
```

Comment: Yes, we need code. Provide a) your controller class b) your FXML file c) the method that loads the FXML file

Comment: How is `firstLoginContainer` assigned? I don't see any code that could change it's value.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the Java code you posted from the class that loads the FXML file you've shown, or is it from the controller class for that FXML file?

Comment: The first piece of code shows my controller methode that loads in a fxml page and if needed adds certain things (in this case the special TextField). the second piece is the FXML of the gridpane.

Comment: Sorry, you're still not being clear (at least to me). If the Java code you've shown is a controller, that means you have two different FXML files. (The one for which this is a controller, and the one you are loading in the method you show.) Can you show the relevant code from *both* FXML files and *both* controller classes?

Comment: i have 2 fxml files. one is loaded and calls the scenesetter to change to my second fml page. so the FXML file is loaded and im not showing wont matter. right? i only have 1 bigass controller (might have to split up later, but shouldnt matter now) which handles all the fxml files.

Comment: Are you saying the controllers for both FXML files are from the same class? Is the FXML code you showed from the FXML that is already loaded, or from the one you are loading in the `sceneSetter` method?

Comment: It seems like you are getting confused between "objects" and "classes". Each FXML file has its own controller. Just because you make all the controllers come from the same class, that doesn't make them the same object. To refine @fabian's question: how are you initializing `firstLoginContainer` *in the controller for the FXML that is already loaded*? I ***very strongly recommend*** using a different class for each controller: it is just way too difficult to keep track of what is initialized and what is not initialized if you have multiple controllers of the same class.

Comment: ill split the controllers up. also i am initializing it through a loginbutton that calls the scenesetter with the right filename and then loads up the fxml and adds something to the grid